# What am I doing wrong when calling `event.preventDefault`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, preventdefault

The function basically removes a user (row) from a table by clicking on a link

I want to prevent the default action for this link with `href = "#"`

```js
linha.find('.botao-remover').on('click', removerUsuarioDoPlacar(event))

function removerUsuarioDoPlacar (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).parent().parent().remove()
}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
    at removerUsuarioDoPlacar (placar.js:29)
    at insereResultadoNoPlacar (placar.js:7)
    at finalizaJogo (main.js:56)
    at main.js:46
```

Comment: Just use the fonction reference when attaching the handler : `on('click', removerUsuarioDoPlacar)`. Does that yield better result ?

Comment: Should be `linha.find('.botao-remover').on('click', removerUsuarioDoPlacar)` and not `linha.find('.botao-remover').on('click', removerUsuarioDoPlacar(event))`

Comment: Thank you, I had confused myself with that detail

Answer (score 1):

```js
linha.find('.botao-remover').on('click', () => {
    removerUsuarioDoPlacar(event)
});
```

Try with this

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Adding some explanations would help others.